# SQL 2017 C# problemas con las fechas

Tags: c#, sql, soap

estoy desarrollando una API SOAP y estoy teniendo algunos problemas con la insercion de fechas...

Tengo una tabla en la que guardo una fecha, el tipo de dato de ese valor es DATE.

En C# tengo una clase llamada "Registro" que tiene como atributo un tipo de dato DateTime:

```
 public class Registro
    {
        private DateTime fecha;
        private string email;
    }
```

En la llamada de la inserción tengo:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public int NuevoRegistro(DateTime fecha, String email)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@cadenaConexion);

            con.Open();

            string sql = "INSERT INTO REGISTRO (Fecha, email) " +
                         "VALUES (@fecha, @email)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = fecha;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =email;
```

A la hora de probarlo y meter una fecha, me salta un error:

```
System.ArgumentException: No se puede convertir 23-02-2019 en System.DateTime.
Nombre del par&#225;metro: type ---> System.FormatException: No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime v&#225;lido.
   en System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   en System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   en System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
   en System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

He probado con dd-MM-YYYY y dd/MM/yyyy y nada. He probado a usar pero sin éxito:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = fecha.toString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Realmente solo necesito guardar la fecha sin la hora. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: haz probado cambiar en el tu clase Registro el tipo de dato a `DATE`

Comment: como invocas el webmethod? porque creo que el problema no es el sql sino el parametro de `NuevoRegistro()`

Comment: Es como dice @LeandroTuttini, el fallo estaba ahi.... cambié el parametro a String y funcionó. Mil gracias!